# Что такое JSON

Tags: json

Что такое JSON и с чем его едят?

Answer (score 3):

если вкратце - JSON это способ представления javascript данных.
Едят, в первую очередь, с **[гуглом](http://google.gik-team.com/?q=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5+json)**

Answer (score 1):

Текстовый формат кодирования сложных данных и не очень. Употребляют вместе с задачами, требующими обмена данными между сервисами (например, между веб-сервером и веб-страницей, работающей в браузере пользователя).

И да, прочтите хотя бы [в википедии про JSON](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Answer (score 1):

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

лично я его использую для передачи многомерных массивов между серверной логикой (php) и клиентской частью (javascript).